# Bootstrap 3 div col pull-right not working properly in mobile view

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap v-3.0.2. And I faced an issue while using pull-right into div col class.
please have a look at following URL.Check both full screen and minimized view.

[Bootstrap-3 issue](http://jsbin.com/EKUtaVe/4/edit)

In Mobile-view both panels are merged. But it should be separate.
Both div panels class has grid axis value 12 (col-xs-12).
If I am try with different value it is working fine.

Is it a bug on bootstrap 3 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `col-sm-push` and `col-sm-pull` instead.

Also, you don't need to use `col-md-6` and `col-lg-6` if you want 50% width columns on any screens larger than `xs`...

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- div's are merged.But It should be one after another -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Right Panel</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
             Right Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Left Panel</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            Left Panel content
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## [Bootply](http://bootply.com/98218)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would need to add `.pull-right` to the columns, but if you add `.clearfix` to the other column, it should resolve this issue.

I think you might get better results using the `.col-xx-pull-x` and `.col-xx-push-x` classes to accomplish the same thing. See the grid documentation "Column Ordering" section for more info on this.